# Can anyone explain about Sudden BSOD while browsing with Firefox and "Video_TDR_Failure" Occurs?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, bsod

PC Specs:

```
Core - i7 6700K
GTX 1070 Sea Hawk X
32 GB Ram
nvme and some HDD, SSD
```

Here is what I got from Event Viewer and a minidump.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qhICuULxM3uCk8LDGUPjj_qxRws75WtH/view?usp=sharing

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting
Date:          29-Sep-23 8:02:46 PM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Gaming-PC
Description:
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000116 (0xffffa38f91e93010, 0xfffff801347523e0, 0xffffffffc000009a, 0x0000000000000004). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\Minidumps\092923-9296-01.dmp. Report Id: d81f8113-47ff-41e1-a038-9929e4d648bc.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting" Guid="{ABCE23E7-DE45-4366-8631-84FA6C525952}" EventSourceName="BugCheck" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-29T14:02:46.1847915Z" />
    <EventRecordID>179313</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Gaming-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">0x00000116 (0xffffa38f91e93010, 0xfffff801347523e0, 0xffffffffc000009a, 0x0000000000000004)</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">C:\Windows\Minidumps\092923-9296-01.dmp</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">d81f8113-47ff-41e1-a038-9929e4d648bc</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Provide the relevant information from the WinDBG analysis

Comment: Did you try anything from the results of searching for `windows 10 video_tdr_failure`

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the NVIDIA driver. What is your video card? Is the driver fully updated? Have you overclocked anything?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry i can't provide that, My windows 10 doesn't have WinDBG...

Comment: @Bravo Yes i tried google search, lots of articles came up but I couldn't find what I was looking for, Therefor my head was spinning to see those posts.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah i did suspect that too, My card is nVidia GTX 1070 Sea Hawk X. Drivers are latest... and I didn't overclock the card, But I have had system overclock, But smooth running for almost a year and no issues came up till yesterday.

Comment: @ShaerAlvyAumi - You will have to Install it if you need our assistance, the only way to determine the source of the crash, is with the analysis provided by that tool. Entirely up to you.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have download his file and analyzed it, which is why I know it's the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: @ShaerAlvyAumi: I suggest undoing the overclock and seeing whether that fixes anything. Just to remark that overclocking can also cause problems that take time to manifest.

Comment: @harrymc Oh Thanks a lot, Now I understand something is wrong with my Graphics card. But actually, Now continuing running this PC for 12 hours+ and nothing happening this time.